# ASCII conversion in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii

I was making an encryption program that would be very easy to make if i could use ascii numbers to represent a character.(using the now deprecated string.translate) Is there a way to pass a character through its ascii number and then append it to a string?

Comment: `"somestring" + chr(65)` ?

Comment: oh...wait, that makes sense. I, wow, am i dumb. jk, i had no idea about this chr function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr):

> Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a'. This is the inverse of ord(). The argument must be in the range [0..255], inclusive; ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range. See also unichr().

And [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string.

Example:

```
print("somestring" + chr(65)) # prints "somestringA"
```

Comment: Thx for the help. An answer should really be an answer, not a comment. @Reut Sharabani But still he for he help